# Is there a way to change the elevation of a BottomSheet?

Tags: flutter

At times, I have to show a [BottomSheet](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html) and a Sandwich at the same time, with the sandwich showing on top of the BottomSheet. Is there a way to change the elevation of the BottomSheet so that it shows under the sandwich?

Comment: Without seeing code I cannot provide an answer apart from... wrapping the widget in Material and set the elevation. `Material(child: yourWidget, elevation: 4.0)`

Answer (score 0):

`elevation` only changes the z-coordinate relative to its parent widget. This only effectively changes the shadow displayed for the widget as mentioned in this [guide](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material/elevation.html).

If what you're referring to as "Sandwich" is the [Drawer](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/drawer), then it's not possible to place the [BottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/showBottomSheet.html) behind the Drawer due to Material design principles.

What you can do here as a workaround is to create an [Animated Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html) that slides from the bottom of the screen. With this approach, the "BottomSheet" which is now an AnimatedContainer can now be displayed behind an opened Drawer.